# Detect changes in Label

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've got a Form with some labels on it. 
From time to time the program changes the text on the labels with

```
label1.Text = "some message"
```

I want to create a function that is executed every time the label text is assigned and implemented an event handler like this:

```
  this.label1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_TextChanged);
  [...]      

  private void label1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // do some stuff
  }
```

This works fine as long as the text is really changed. But if the text is set to the same value it already has, the event doesn't execute. Is there an easy way to hook a function into the text assignment without changing every occurence of `label1.Text = ...` to a custom function call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Control's Text property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.text.aspx) is virtual so you can create your own label control and add custom functionality there, such as raising an event when the property's setter is called even if it doesn't result in changed text.

Answer (score 0):

Set the label text via property every time program set its value it will call that function that u will define in property.

like

```
public string LabelText 
{
   set
   {
    label1.Text = value;

    // your  Function Calling

    }
}
```

Comment: This would require rewriting every instance of the text assignment, which I wanted to avoid. dkackman's solution works best for me, since I can leave the original form untouched, except for a redeclaration of the Label as MyLabel